# Solving $\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-3}=\sqrt{3x+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I try to solve this equation:
$$\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-3}=\sqrt{3x+4}$$

So what i did was:

$$x+2+2*\sqrt{x+2}*\sqrt{x-3}+x-3=3x+4$$

$$2*\sqrt{x+2}*\sqrt{x-3}=x+5$$

$$4*{(x+2)}*(x-3)=x^2+25+10x$$

$$4x^2-4x-24=x^2+25+10x$$

$$3x^2-14x-49$$

But this seems to be wrong! What did i wrong?

Comment: typo: $3x+4$ instead of $3x+5$

Comment: Sorry this was a typo but its still false

Comment: What is the "this" that seems to be wrong, and what makes you think it's wrong?  (The only thing I see amiss is the lack of an "$=0$" in the last line.  And, of course, not continuing on to a factorization of the quadratic.  Everything else you've done is perfectly fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first step on the right hand side should be $3x+5$ not $3x+4$

Then proceeding the same way:
$$
\begin{split}
4(x^2-x-6) &= x^2 + 12x + 36 \\
3x^2 - 16x - 60 &= 0
\end{split}
$$
Since the discriminant of that equation is $16^2 - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 60 < 0$ there are no solutions.

**UPDATE** you changed the problem now, so you get
$4(x^2-x-6) = x^2 + 10x + 25$ which results in a quadratic $3x^2 - 14x - 49 = 0$ so $(x-7)(3x+7)=0$ and $x=7$ or $x = -7/3$. The second solution is impossible (drives roots to be complex) so $x=7$ is the only one.

Comment: Sorry this was a typo but its still not correct

Comment: @JohnSmith see the update

Answer (score 2):

Note: the original question read $= \sqrt{3x + 5}$ instead of $= \sqrt{3x + 4}$. There is no problem with the fixed question. Maybe just that it's unfinished. The final line should read $3x^2 - 14x + 49 = 0$ rather than just $x^2 - 14x + 49$. After that, solve the quadratic; only one of the solutions ($7$) to the quadratic gives a solution to the original equation (the other ($-7/3$) was introduced by the squaring operations).

Original response: the $3x + 4$ instead of $3x + 5$ on the first line seems a genuine mistake, rather than a typo; you continue with it.

Comment: Its still wrong!

Comment: Yes, you have to change the $4$ in a $5$ and then fix the rest accordingly.

Comment: Ok, you fixed the question, rather than the solution.

Comment: So, what's the problem now? Solve the quadratic $3x^2 - 14x - 49 = 0$; $7$ is a solution (and the other solution to the quadratic is not).

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think you've done anything wrong? You can factorise
$$3x^2-14x-49 = (3x+7)(x-7)$$
to obtain a solution to your equation.

Beware: one of the solutions from this quadratic is not a solution because it doesn't satisfy the original equation... this often happens when you solve equations by squaring stuff.

*P.S. I must have reached the question after the typo was fixed.*